# Creating new variable based on condition

Tags: r

I have a want to create a new variable that is basically taking the value of an existing variable, but it is conditional.  You have var1 and var2 that are both numeric. The new variable should take either var1 or var2, whichever is lower.

Example code (trying this just replicated var1):

```
upc_data_actual2$price9 <- if(upc_data_actual2$MSRP_PRC<upc_data_actual2$price){
  upc_data_actual2$price9=upc_data_actual2$MSRP_PRC
} else {
  upc_data_actual2$price=upc_data_actual2$price
}
```

Comment: Maybe an if/else condition is a good start

Comment: `new_variable <- min(var1, var2)`

Comment: Doing this just yields 0: upc_data_actual2$price8 <- min(upc_data_actual2$MSRP_PRC, upc_data_actual2$price)

Comment: Try .  `pmin(var1, var2)`.

Comment: pmin(var1, var2) works - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var1=5
 var2=4
 t=0
 if (var1<var2) {
   t=var1
 } else {
   t=var2
 }
 print(t)
 Takes the smaller variable and puts it into another
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this and it just replicated var1. See below for example code:
upc_data_actual2$price9 <- if(upc_data_actual2$MSRP_PRC<upc_data_actual2$price){
  upc_data_actual2$price9=upc_data_actual2$MSRP_PRC
} else {
  upc_data_actual2$price=upc_data_actual2$price
}